# why is my game's "game over screen" need to be dragged outside of view for it to show?

Tags: java

If you miss clicking the circle three times, it should end the game. Well, it does but the game over screen doesn't show unless I drag the window out of view and back. Why?

The code's foundation was from youtuber Bro Code's snake game. I'm still learning java so his video was really helpful. I've understood some concepts he used and I used it to make this game.

Below are the three classes in the project:

main class

```
public class AimGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

game frame class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame{
    GameFrame() {
        GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();
        this.add(panel);
        this.setTitle("Aim 2D");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

game panel class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1000;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int DELAY = 75;
    int circlesClicked = 0;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;

    //
    JPanel clockPanel;
    JLabel clock;
    long startTime;
    long endTime;
    //
    long elapsedSeconds;
    long elapsedTenthSeconds;
    //
    int xClick;
    int yClick;
    int gridHitX;
    int gridHitY;
    //
    int life=3;
    //

    GamePanel() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        random = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame() {
        spawnTarget();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
        timer.start();
        clockMethod();
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        if (running) {
            // optional grid
            for(int i=0; i<SCREEN_WIDTH/UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
                g.drawLine(0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i*UNIT_SIZE);
                g.drawLine(i*UNIT_SIZE, 0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
            }

            // apple
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);

            // score
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 40));
            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(circlesClicked),(SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth(String.valueOf(circlesClicked)))/2,2*g.getFont().getSize());
        }
        else {
            gameOver(g);
        }
    }

    public void newTargetCoords() {
        appleX = random.nextInt(SCREEN_WIDTH/UNIT_SIZE)*UNIT_SIZE;
        appleY = random.nextInt(SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE)*UNIT_SIZE;
    }

    public void spawnTarget() {
        newTargetCoords();
    }

    public void checkTarget() {
        // gridify clicked coords
        gridHitX = ((xClick/UNIT_SIZE))*UNIT_SIZE;
        gridHitY = ((yClick/UNIT_SIZE))*UNIT_SIZE;
        //
        if ((gridHitX == appleX)&&(gridHitY == appleY)) {
            circlesClicked++;
            spawnTarget();
        } else {
            missTarget();
        }
    }

    public void missTarget() {
        // subtract 1 life
        life--;
        if(life==0) {
            running = false;
        }
        if (!running) {
             timer.stop();
        }
    }

    public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
        // score
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 20));
        FontMetrics metrics1 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("score: " + circlesClicked,(SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics1.stringWidth("score: " + circlesClicked))/2,3*g.getFont().getSize());

        // Game Over text
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        FontMetrics metrics2 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("game over",(SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics2.stringWidth("game over"))/2,SCREEN_HEIGHT/2);
    }

    public void restartGame() {
        setVisible(false);
        new GameFrame();
    }

    public void clockMethod() {
        clockPanel = new JPanel();

        clock = new JLabel("00:00");

        clockPanel.add(clock);

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        add(clockPanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (running) {
        } else {
            checkTarget();
        }
        repaint();

        if(timer.isRunning())
        {
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // elapsed quarter seconds for spawns
            elapsedTenthSeconds = (endTime-startTime)/100;

            // put elapsed seconds into variable
            elapsedSeconds = (endTime-startTime)/1000;

            // declare formatting
            int min = (int)elapsedSeconds/60;
            int sec = (int)elapsedSeconds%60;
            String minStr = (min<10 ? "0" : "")+min;
            String secStr = (sec<10 ? "0" : "")+sec;

            // display elapsed time (minutes:seconds)
            clock.setText(minStr+":"+secStr);

            // spawn circle

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        xClick=e.getX();
        yClick=e.getY();
        checkTarget();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    // restart by pressing 'R'
    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_R) {
                restartGame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manipulating the placement of [life--] and [missTarget();]

```
    public void checkTarget() {
        gridify();
        //
        if ((gridHitX == appleX)&&(gridHitY == appleY)) {
            circlesClicked++;
            spawnTarget();
        } else {
            missTarget();
            // subtract 1 life
            life--;
        }
    }

    public void missTarget() {
        if(life==0) {
            running = false;
        }
        if (!running) {
             timer.stop();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (running) {
            missTarget();
        }

        if(timer.isRunning())
        {
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // elapsed quarter seconds for spawns
            elapsedTenthSeconds = (endTime-startTime)/100;

            // put elapsed seconds into variable
            elapsedSeconds = (endTime-startTime)/1000;

            // declare formatting
            int min = (int)elapsedSeconds/60;
            int sec = (int)elapsedSeconds%60;
            String minStr = (min<10 ? "0" : "")+min;
            String secStr = (sec<10 ? "0" : "")+sec;

            // display elapsed time (minutes:seconds)
            clock.setText(minStr+":"+secStr);

            // spawn circle
        }
        repaint();
    }
```